# When using zeus in zsh cursor position shifts after the the termination of zeus command

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, terminal, zsh, zeus

Sometimes there is a strange issue with terminal cursor in zsh when zeus command was terminated.
The position of cursor shifts and each line of the output in the console has extra indentation, e.g.

```
           services GET        /services(.:format)                                services#index
                         payments GET        /payments(.:format)                                payments#index
                                        orders_verify POST       /orders_verify(.:format)                           orders_verify#index
                                                        orders GET        /orders(.:format)                                  orders#index
        diets GET        /diets(.:format)                                   diets#index
```

The only way to fix that is to open a new terminal window/tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Staircasing is unrelated to **locale**.  Full-screen programs manipulate the terminal-mode settings to let them read single characters from the screen as well as send special characters (such as carriage return and line-feed) to the screen without having the terminal driver "translate" them.

The quick fix — run this command:

```
reset
```

(you may have to press <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> after typing "reset" to enter this properly)

Further reading:

- [**`tset`**, **`reset`** - terminal initialization](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set LOCALE environment vars to UTF-8 in your .zshrc file

1. Open .zshrc

   ```
   vim ~/.zshrc
   ```
2. Add these lines

   ```
   export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

   export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
   ```
3. Close the file (Shift-ZZ) and reload it in the current session (or open a new terminal window/tab)

   ```
   . ~/.zshrc
   ```